# Tratamento de erro na API Google maps Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, google, maps

Estou fazendo um cadastro de pessoas com endereço para mostrar no mapa onde determinada pessoa mora. Quando digito o endereço correto tudo funciona normalmente, mas quando erro o endereço, que não é válido para o **Google Maps**, o app fecha.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    FragmentActivity context = getActivity();
    LatLng local = new Localizador(context).getCoordenada("R. Eurita, 47 - Santa Teresa - Belo Horizonte - MG");
    centralizaNo(local);

    AlunoDAO dao = new AlunoDAO(context);
    List<Aluno> alunos = dao.getLista();

    for (Aluno aluno : alunos) {

        GoogleMap map = getMap();

        LatLng localAluno = new Localizador(context).getCoordenada(aluno.getEndereco());

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().title(aluno.getNome()).position(localAluno);
        map.addMarker(options );

    }

    dao.close();
}

public void centralizaNo(LatLng local) {
    GoogleMap map = getMap();
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(local , 15);
    map.animateCamera(update );
}
```

Queria uma ajuda para tratar o erro e se a pessoa digitar um endereço inválido não aparecer no mapa para fluir normalmente.

```
public class Localizador {
    private Context context;

    public Localizador(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public LatLng getCoordenada(String endereco) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);

        try {
            List<Address> enderecos = geocoder.getFromLocationName(endereco, 1);
            if (!enderecos.isEmpty()){

                Address enderecoLocalizado = enderecos.get(0);
                double latitude = enderecoLocalizado.getLatitude();
                double longitude = enderecoLocalizado.getLongitude();

                return new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque também o código da classe `Localizador`.

Comment: Pronto, publicado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o seu método `getCoordenada` já retorna um valor nulo caso não encontre o endereço informado, basta você fazer uma verificação antes de utilizar uma coordenada para definir um local, independente de onde seja.

Assim mais ou menos:

```
Localizador localizador = new Localizador(context);
LatLng localAluno = localizador.getCoordenada(aluno.getEndereco());

if (localAluno != null) {
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().title(aluno.getNome()).position(localAluno);
    map.addMarker(options);
}
```

Assim você previne qualquer exceção que de fato realmente ocorre caso a posição definida com `position()` seja nula.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo!